# Copying selected files to NSArray from another NSArray in ios using pattern matching

Tags: ios, regex, nsarray, nsregularexpression

I have an `NSArray` which contains all files present in my documents folder of my app.

Here is array declaration code,

```
    NSArray * filePathsArray ;
    filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];
    NSLog(@"Number of images in my app folder %d",[filePathsArray count]);
```

Now I want to copy files which starts with name "snap" `(for ex: snap1 , snap2, snapRecent ...)`
to another `NSArray`.

How to do this using pattern matching? I am new to iOS development.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `- (NSArray *)filteredArrayUsingPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate` to filter the objects that match your pattern. For example, something like the following should make the trick:

```
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[cd] %@", predicateFilter];
NSArray *filteredArray = [filePathsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should hlp

```
NSString *startPattern = @"snap";
for (NSString *filePath in filePathsArray) {
    if (filePath.length < startPattern.length) {
        continue;
    }
    if ([[filePath substringToIndex:startPattern.length] isEqualToString:startPattern]) {
        // copy files
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it:

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: 5];
for (NSString *string in filePathsArray)
    if ([string rangeOfString: @"snap"].location == 0)
        [newArray addObject: string];

NSLog(@"%@", newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer regular expressions, you use `NSRegularExpression` class. Link:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Example below.

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^snap" options:0 error:&error];
//check for error here
NSMutableArray *filteredArray = [NSMutableArray array];

[filePathsArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){

    NSRange rangeOfFirstMatch = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:obj options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [obj length])];

    if (!NSEqualRanges(rangeOfFirstMatch, NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0))) {

        [filteredArray addObject:obj];

    }

} ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that `subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath` will perform a deep enumeration over your folder (it will search all subfolders as well) and will return paths relative to the base folder. In order to find all files in any of these folders that begin with `snap`, you could do something like this:

```
NSArray * filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath: documentsDirectory  error:nil];
NSIndexSet *indexes = [filePathsArray indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    return (BOOL)([[obj lastPathComponent] hasPrefix:@"snap"] && ![[[obj lastPathComponent] pathExtension] isEqualToString:@""]);
}];
NSArray *matches = [filePathsArray objectsAtIndexes:indexes];
```

Now `matches` array will contain the paths of all the files starting with `snap` (**excluding** folders that may start with `snap`). Paths will be relative to the directory you have passed for enumeration.

Comment: @user1814464 You're welcome. Consider marking the answer as correct if that's what you're looking for.